# Change background of a row in a drawCallback DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How can I change the background of a row that has a specific value in a cell inside a drawCallback?

```
 $(table_id).DataTable({
    //...
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
             // here for each row, if row['type'] != "" then row.bgcolor ="yellow"
        },
```

This is the complete snippet that render my table:

```
 $(table_id).DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        serverSide: true,
        "processing": true,
        rowId: 'MessageID',
        ajax: {
            url: '/Controller/myRoute',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {table_id: table_id},
        },
        "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {

        },
        "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
            console.log("data is" + data);
        },
        columns: [
           {
               data: "Date",
               "sortable": true,
               "render": function (data) {
                   var formatted = data;
                   if (data.indexOf("/Date(") !== -1) {
                       var date = new Date(parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                       formatted = date.toString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
                   }
                   return formatted;
               }
           },
           { data: "Message_id"},
           { data: "From_id"},
           { data: "Message_text" },
        ]
    });
    } 
});
```

Inside /Controller/MyRoute I have code that retrieves 10 object from a DB and return them as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use `createdRow` callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "createdRow": function (tr, tdsContent) {
            if(tdsContent[4] === 'A') {
             tr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
        }});
});
```

```html
   
<html>  <head>  <title>Row color</title>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      
      
  </head>

    <body>
            
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td> 4</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td>8.5</td>
            <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
          
</body></html>
```

Comment: Hey Gudz, I have to do it inside the drawCallback since my datatable retrieves data serverside using ajax, every time a new row is added I trigger the ajax.reload on the table and the createdRow callback is called for all the rows that I retrieve and it is not the kind of behavior I am try to accomplish...I need something that runs after the table is drawn in order to highlight rows with specific values...

Comment: can you provide code snippet with your ajax example? I'm sure there is a way to use `createdRow` callback by moving your ajax call to another place or something like this

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution on another callback:

JavaScript:

```
 "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
            if (data.type !== '') {
                $(row).addClass('colored-row');
            }
        }
```

And then style it with css:

```
.colored-row{background-color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is a few years old. But I too was looking for the solution for this and stumbled across here. I was able to figure it out and figured I'd share my answer.

```
$(table_id).DataTable({
//...
"drawCallback": function (e) {
    var api = this.api();
    for (var i = 0; api.rows().count() > i; i++) {
        var rowData = api.row(i).data();
        var rowNode = api.row(i).node();
        var cellNode = api.cell(i, 1).node(); // Can apply same logic to just a cell 
                                 // want specific cell to be bolded or some other style --cell(row, column)
        if (rowData.type != "") {
            $(rowNode).addClass("row-attention");
            $(cellNode).addClass("cell-attention");
        } else { // remove the class in case it was previously added
            $(rowNode).removeClass("row-attention");
            $(cellNode).removeClass("cell-attention");
        }
    }
},
```

And the following Styling. I personally needed the !important but potentially might not be needed depending on ordering of your stylesheets.

```
.row-attention {
    background-color: #FFFF00 !important;
}

.cell-attention {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```